# Applying for ESTA with (second) Russian citizenship

Tags: usa, esta, russian-citizens

Asking on behalf of a family member, who is a British citizen, permanently resident in the UK, but who also has a Russian citizenship. The plan it to travel to the USA in April 2023. In the current political climate, anything related to Russia or Russian citizens is viewed with suspicion, so I'm looking for some confirmed cases of ESTA actually being issued to those that have Russian citizenship.

Of course the idea is to fly with the British passport, but the ESTA application does ask about other citizenships.

The question is not about "what are the chances of getting/not getting it", but rather "are there confirmed cases of ESTA being issued to those with Russian citizenship".

**Updated:** application was submitted - and approved the next day. Initially it did say "could not be approved automatically", which caused some anxiety, but then it was approved, so all good there.

Comment: Just pay 21$ and find out?

Comment: If someone answers ‘yes’, it doesn’t necessarily mean that other applicants would be successful

Comment: This is rather opinion based, I agree with @Traveller comment.

Comment: There are second nationalities (currently Iran, Iraq, North Korea, Sudan, and Syria) that would disallow you from using the Visa Waiver Program with a VWP-eligible nationality. Russian nationality is not currently one of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current political climate aside, having one citizenship from an ESTA eligible country and another from a non-ESTA eligible country is not unusual. Of course, you must declare this.

Being Russian is not going to lead to an automatic refusal, just like being British will not lead to an automatic approval. It's worth noting that Russian nationals may still enter the US, provided they have the correct documentation. In your relative's case, that would be an ESTA, through their British nationality.

Personally, I would just apply.

Comment: Application was submitted - and approved the next day. Initially it did say "could not be approved automatically", which caused some anxiety, but then it was approved, so all good there.

Comment: "Being Russian is not going to lead to an automatic refusal" - I'm not so sure about this, considering my recent experience when my visa application was refused for purely made up reasons.

Comment: @user626528 I can't comment on your case. It's not official policy to ban Russian nationals from entering the US, or from requesting documentation to enter the US.

Comment: @async there is no **official** policy, exactly. But having much more supporting docs than what was enough to get a visa some 5 years ago, is not enough today.